# __FILE__ in WordPress plugins

Tags: plugins

I'm using [Sidebar Generator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sidebar-generator/) in all my themes.

The plugin works perfectly normal from "plugins" directory, but I want to embed it somehow to my themes, so it won't display on Installed Plugins list.

I've just copied sidebar_generator.php (the whole code is luckily in one file) to mytheme/plugins and included it in functions.php

```
require_once (MY_PLUGINS . '/sidebar_generator.php');
```

Now, it worked for all other plugins, but not for this one! This way when I click on "Sidebars" it refreshes the actual page instead of loading plugin's admin_page.

Any ideas why is it happening and how to make it working?

I believe the problem lays here:

```
add_submenu_page('themes.php', 'Sidebars', 'Sidebars', 'manage_options', __FILE__, array('sidebar_generator','admin_page'));
```

Chaning **FILE** to something else helps, but I'm not sure how to point this submenu link at the actual plugins admin page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work (and does when I test on a new WP install) with `__FILE__`, though it's not recommended because it exposes the server path and is just generally an ugly URL. You can replace it with a unique identifier like 'sb-generator-options' or whatever really, as long as it's unique. the important part is the last param that tells it what function to use to render the page.

Are you maybe moving `add_submenu_page` out of the plugin file, or are you just editing it in place?

Answer (score -3):

The `__FILE__` will return full path with filename of the file.
It's magic method of PHP.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?